# Making a countdown clock that resets and changes the page content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm slowly learning to implement Javascript into my websites to generate automated changes, actual code is scary for my graphic designer approach but I think I'm getting there.

I followed an exercise some time ago that had me make a countdown clock that resets every time it reaches 0, nothing to crazy but it got me thinking:

Is there any way to make that reset affect the content of the entire page?

The practical case that made me think of it is the website of a restaurant that has a different coupon every day of the week, they upload the coupon code to their social media everyday but if I could develop a site that loops the codes depending on the day and make it change the text content and the stylesheet on it's own the process would be automatic.

I can't figure out how you'd link the clock reset to that change though, tried searching for it and I think this might be solved with some AJAX shenanigans, but it seems to be a bit too specific to find, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"Is there any way to make that reset affect the content of the entire page?"_ Yes. However your question is too broad and will probably be closed. Also realize that if you did do that, anyone could see the coupon codes within your JavaScript at any time, not just when you present them.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. This is a very general question. It is hard to answer without specificity that requires knowledge the community doesn't have. For example:

1. When you say "I followed an exercise some time ago...", what did the code look like? What was your final product? How is JavaScript used?

When asking a question in stackoverflow, it can be helpful to share a snippet of what the code looks like so that others can help by testing the code themselves and giving feedback. Or at the very least observing the functionality and maybe catching small syntax errors.

2. To the second point of "Is there any way to make that reset affect the content of the entire page?" Yes. There are MANY MANY MANY ways to affect content of a page, either in pieces or in its entirety. Once again it depends on what you want to do with the code that YOU have specifically. Even with the basic tools of HTML and JavaScript you can do this. You don't need "AJAX shenanigans" LOL.

If you are just starting out, dig deep into the basics of JavaScript(if that is your preferred language). You will find a whole host of versatile functionality through creating objects, methods, manipulating the DOM, building your own event handlers, etc. Also if none of what I just wrote makes any sense, then you now have some terms worth researching on your own.

I hope that this is helpful for you, and I wish you the best of luck on your coding journey.